# Automate Sending Google Sheet with Gmail in editable format

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I try to make a code that allows me to send by mail, a google sheet as an attachment and to edit its contents. 
I try with this code, but it gives me error in the table.
As it would be the complete code so that the google sheet could be sent by mail, every week and
with its original format.

```
function emailStats() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var subject = "Daily Report of Customer Service Statistics";
  MailApp.sendEmail("inter@gmail.com", subject, createTable(data));

}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with createTable.  Is that something you wrote?

Comment: Can you also provide the error received when running the script?

Comment: I attach the error that I get when I run. Thank you.    

ReferenceError: "createTable" is not defined. (line 6, file "Code")

Comment: I want to send to 2  email addresses, "Sheet 1",  that are part of a Spreadsheet. I am interested in receiving the destination mail every 8 days as an attachment and can be edited. Thank you.